# GFCI breaker sticker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I recently added a new GFCI circuit for a Nema 14-30R dryer. The GFCI breaker came with this sticker. Do I really need to attach the 2 labels? If yes where? Instructions say:

1. attach to the front surface of the enclosure
2. attach to the inside surface of the trim or of the enclosure

Should I attach the 1st label on the subpanel cover and the 2nd label inside the subpanel? Do I need any sticker on the dryer outlet?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stickers required by Code is "GFCI Protected" at the receptacle, and "No Equipment Ground" if that is true.  *

By "required" I mean if your outlet is required to be GFCI protected and that sticker isn't there, that's a violation.  Also NEC 110.3 requires you to follow the instructions *which UL approves as part of approving the equipment*, and that says to deploy the GFCI Protected label.

As for applying this sticker, you have to consult the installation instructions which UL approved as part of the listing. This doesn't appear to be that.  This appears to be Siemens' attempt to reduce costs by helping you diagnose GFCI problems more efficiently. Your call.  The time you save may be your own.

* If you are GFCI protecting a non-grounded 3-wire dryer connection (that 3rd wire is neutral not ground), then NEC directly requires the No Equipment Ground label *and* the GFCI Protected label. Make sure you disconnect the neutral-ground bonding strap in the dryer, otherwise the GFCI is more likely to have nuisance trips.

Comment: I'm familiar with the GFCI Protected sticker requirement at the receptacle so I was expecting a sticker for that. I'll have to make my own sticker for the receptacle. My new circuit has 4 wires (hot-hot-neutral-ground), I've removed the neutral-ground bonding strap and I've verified infinite resistance between neutral and ground on the dryer that you previously recommended measuring. Since it sounds these 2 labels aren't required by code I'll only attach the 1st one inside the panel (and not outside) to help with troubleshooting and skip the 2nd label.

Comment: @user162793 you can make the GFCI Protected label any way you please, as long as it's not hand-written.